# Placing illustrator logos in Indesign retains artboard dimensions (dead space around actual logo)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

My I need to export Print+Web versions of logos in several formats currently arranged in artboards but whenever I
 - save as... EPS
 - [tick "Use Artboards"]

... the resulting files *when placed in Indesign* have empty space around the logo, making it impossible in Indesign to enter exact dimensions, or positioning... and it's driving me a little nuts.

Comment: Don't check use Artboards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the **Import Options** when importing into InDesign, you have a choice as to what InDesign uses as the boundaries.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott! Unfortunately, this only fixes things on my end, I fear the people I hand the logos to will have this issue.
Is there a way to export **loosing** the artboard frame?

Comment: No. This is **entirely** controlled by InDesign. You can't do anything in Illustrator to override it. The best you could do is to size your artboard exactly to the size of the art in Illustrator. Trying to control it for the end user is like a car dealer trying to control how you drive the car they sold you.